# Add Buttons in getView function of Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-button, baseadapter

I am adding buttons inside my `getview()` function of Custom Adapter.
I am adding buttons along with my messages of a chat application.

Here is the code to add message-

```
view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_recv,null);
BubbleTextView text_message= (BubbleTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
text_message.setText(list_chat_models.get(position).message);
```

The messages part has nothing to do with the buttons part, except the view variable.
This part is for adding buttons-

```
 LinearLayout vgjp = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.message_layout);
for (int j = 0; j < numOfbuttons ; j++) {
    Button btn1 = (Button) new Button(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn1.setId(j+1);
    btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
    btn1.setText(btnlist.get(j));
    btn1.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    btn1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.design_default_color_background);
   vgjp.addView(btn1);
}
```

The problem is, the buttons get applied to all the messages.

Where Am I going wrong???

EDIT-
here is complete code of getView function for more clarity-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view= convertView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            if(list_chat_models.get(position).isSend){
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_send,null);
                BubbleTextView text_message= (BubbleTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
                text_message.setText(list_chat_models.get(position).message);
            }

            else{
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_recv,null);
                BubbleTextView text_message= (BubbleTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_message);
                text_message.setText(list_chat_models.get(position).message);

                MainActivity bt = new MainActivity();
                btnlist = MainActivity.btlist;
                int numOfbuttons;
                fileObject = MainActivity.fileObject;
                
                if( fileObject.has("buttons")){ 
                    numOfbuttons = btnlist.size();
                    LinearLayout vgjp = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.message_layout);

                    for (int j = 0; j < numOfbuttons ; j++) {
                        final Button btn1 = (Button) new Button(context);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        btn1.setId(j+1);
                        btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
                        btn1.setText(btnlist.get(j));
                        btn1.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
                        btn1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.design_default_color_background);
                        vgjp.addView(btn1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: you want to do this for a certain row/message?

Comment: I assume your are using recyclerView. which recycle the view. you will have to clean  your  `LinearLayout vgjp`  and run your code every time you bind the view holder `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: @Zain Yes I want to add the buttons only to the last message.
But its getting added to all the messages of  `list_item_message_recv`

Comment: @sonique No, I am not using recyclerview.
I am using a ListView and a CustomAdapter.
The codes given above are from getView() function of the CustomAdapter which returns a view.

Comment: I have added the complete getView function for more clearity.
Please have a look @Zain